# C pointers to pointers. Why the need to have two asterisks?

Tags: c, pointers

In C a pointer to another pointer is represented with two asterisks `**`. Is this for legibility purpose or is there something else to it? I used one asterisk to make a pointer point to another pointer and I got the same result:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int *p = &a;
    int *p2 = p;

    printf("val: %p", p2);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int *p = &a;
    int **p2 = p;

    printf("val: %p", p2);
}
```

Both give me the right address being pointed to, so what gives?

Comment: please provide the command you used to build the last example.

Comment: `int **p2 = p;` should at the very least give you a warning since you're assigning to a pointer of the wrong type.

Comment: No warnings, no errors. I used CodeBlocks IDE for building.

Comment: `int **p2 = p;` is an error. If you get no warnings then you should operate your compiler in standard mode, e.g. for gcc, `-std=c99`. There may also be other warning levels you can turn up.

Comment: The second does not compile on my machine in a .cpp file with mingw, it is a type error.

Comment: There isn't a pointer pointing to another pointer anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: "No warnings, no errors. I used CodeBlocks IDE for building." -- Then you haven't configured it properly.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I do not understand why you guys say I am assigning a pointer of the wrong type?

Answer (score 3):

Pointers look the same at runtime. They're typed for semantic reasons. What you're basically asking is "why should I need to give my pointer a meaningful type?"

In a high-level programming language, variables have types to aid with clarity and to allow the compiler to find mistakes you might otherwise miss.

Comment: So, are you saying the extra asterisk is simply for semantics and both ways are equivalent? Please clarify.

Comment: @polymorph If you always know what you are doing, then yes.

Comment: If you ignore the pointer type information, then yes. But if you are going to ignore pointer type information you may as well use `void *` for all pointers.

Comment: "is simply for semantics" -- There is nothing **but** semantics in proper programming; the days of computers just being a bunch of bits are long gone. "and both ways are equivalent" -- no; improperly typed programs do not conform to the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **p2 = p;
```

This line may not do what you think, it results in the following case (where `->` denotes points to)

```
p  -> a
p2 -> a
```

while this line

```
int **p2 = &p;
```

will result in something more meaningful:

```
p  -> a
p2 -> p -> a
```

This first line (yours) does not make sense. You've assigned a pointer to a pointer to be a pointer to an integer, it should error or warning as it's the wrong type. Using code blocks, recompile WITHOUT running and you will see if it has a warning. When it runs it will hide the warnings.

Use of double asterix and double pointers is not just for show, it is a completely different type and the use of one or the other allows you and the compiler to reason about the code.

Comment: if g++ compiles this with a warning, then that's a compiler bug. have you established that there is such a bug. it's far more likely a PEBCAK issue.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have not, I'm merely responding to the OP comment that the line compiled for him.

Comment: we can be reasonably sure that the OP can not be trusted on that issue.

Comment: Just tested, `**p2 = p;` causes an error with mingw.

Comment: @Alf, as long as the compiler emits a diagnostic, it can do what else it likes

Comment: @MattMcNabb: only in the formal. in the marketplace (if I can use that term) a compiler that generally emits warnings for hard errors, will just not be used by the competent. g++ is known as a bit perverse, exploiting just about every formal loophole to implement counter-productive unpredictable corner-case "optimizations", but that's its thing: it does not fail to diagnose hard errors properly as such (then it would be unusable).

Comment: It has to allow `int **p2 = (int **)p;`  , and I don't see much difference between that and allowing `int **p2 = p;` while emitting a warning message that this is probably stupid.  The competent all use their compiler in standard mode and with warning levels turned up anyway, right ;)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: there's a difference between invalid code, and probably stupid but technically valid code. compilers are not obliged by the C++ standard to differentiate between these cases. but they are so obliged by existing practice and the marketplace. not every competent c++ programmer is keen on "clean compiles". some, like the current secretary of the c++ standard, have instead argued that it's futile and not work-saving to attempt to get rid of warnings, so i suspect his compiles have reams of warnings that he just ignores, sure that as long as his code is valid it ain't dumb.

Comment: just realizing that the tag "C++" is incorrect for the question, that the question is about C. in C it's not an error, but both gcc and visual c++ emit warning.

Answer (score 0):

For the second case, try printing:

```
**p2;
```

Since a double pointer is an address of an address, you are assuming that `*p` (single indirection) gives you what you want, but you can't do a `**p` (double indirection) on it. And hence the difference.

On the other hand, above (`**p` operation) will give you the right result if you do:

```
int a = 2;
int *p = &a;
int **p2 = &p;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to explain with a picture, but I'll try without. Let's imagine, for the sake of example, that the C compiler allocates space for our variables starting at memory address 10000.  Then, the declarations

```
int a = 5, *p = &a, **pp = &p;
```

allocates space for three values: the (let's assume 32 bits) 4 bytes at address 10000 will contain the value 5. The next 4 bytes at address 10004 will contain the value 10000. And the four bytes at address 10008 contain the value 10004.

So yes, you need both stars to perform the indirection twice. `*pp` is 10004, and `**pp` is 5.

There are a few places where C plays a bit fast and loose with addresses: one is arrays. The name of an array is a pointer to its first element, but the address operator on an array does not give a pointer to a pointer: that is, if you define:

```
int a[10];
```

then `a` and `&a` are the same thing, which is stupid, but that's the way it is.

Also, you can generally pass a pointer of any kind or any level to functions like `memset()`, because an address is an address if you don't care what it points to.

Comment: In the last example, `a` and `&a` are different, and the expression `a == &a` is an error. To get it to work you need to cast one of the values, e.g. `a == (int *)&a`.  This reflects the fact that the address of the first int of `a` is the same as the address of the first int-sized chunk of memory contained in `a` , i.e. that arrays cannot have initial padding.

Comment: " the address operator on an array does not give a pointer to a pointer" -- nor should it, because `a` is not a pointer, it's an array, and `&a` yields the address of the array. "then a == &a, which is stupid" -- not. Arrays decay to pointers when used as expressions, so it's the plain `a` that is being interpreted as the address of the array rather than the array itself, so these expressions have the same value -- but not the same type, as Matt points out, so that comparison isn't valid as is.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit sloppy here in that the actual comparison as written is wrong. But I do still think it's a mistake that arrays become pointers sometimes and don't other times--it makes things like this harder to explain than if it were consistent. For example, a function that takes a pointer to int argument could be called with either `f(a)` or `f(&a)`. Add C++ references, and I'm surprised anyone can get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation that the second example code compiled, is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int *p = &a;
    int **p2 = p;

    printf("val: %p", p2);
}
```

Compiling with [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e213f69d763eebcb), which uses `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic`:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:16: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' in initialization
     int **p2 = p;
                ^
main.cpp:9:25: warning: format '%p' expects argument of type 'void*', but argument 2 has type 'int**' [-Wformat=]
     printf("val: %p", p2);
                         ^
```

---

Also, please see the [C++ FAQ item about how to post a question about code that doesn't work](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html), especially points 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: Code DOES WORK. Please try before you think it's bad code. I mentioned it was compiled with CodeBlocks and GCC and it does as I posted above.

Comment: @polymorph: Please respond to my question about build command, which was the first comment on your question. Neither your question nor your comments so far have mentioned GCC, AFAICT. Instead the question is tagged as C++ (and as C). There is no *assumption* of "bad code", and I haven't given that value judgment. However, now that you mention it, yes it's bad. The inherent badness is the reason why it's *invalid* as C++ code, and that even compiled as only C code gcc emits a warning.

Comment: You may have noticed am I a complete beginner to C, don't ask to much. I created the question with the knowledge available to me I didn't know I should be mentioning the exact language and compiler because I think C and C++ behave almost the same way. I think you're just making it much more difficult for me to understand the concept because again I am a beginner. Please simplify your answers and thank you. @Cheers and hth. - Alf